# Render Table in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render the {DataRow} on my application. I used `<tbody>{DataRow()}</tbody>` but I it says it expects an argument and when I pass `data`, I still don't get the result I want. How can I fix this?

```
const Task7: React.FC = () => {
  const { users, error } = useSWR("/api/users", fetchData);
  return (
      <table className="data__table">
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
        {
          <tbody>{DataRow()}</tbody>
        }
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};
const DataRow: React.FC<Users> = (data) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{data.id}</td>
      <td>{data.name}</td>
      <td>{data.age}</td>
      <td>{data.email}</td>
    </tr>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally don't *directly invoke* a component like a function.  Use it like a component.  For example:

```
<tbody><DataRow /></tbody>
```

Your specific component is also expecting props called `id`, `name`, `age`, and `email`.  Where do those come from?  Is your `users` value an array of objects with those peoperties?  If so, you'd loop over that array and output the components with those props.  For example:

```
<tbody>
  {users.map(u => <DataRow {...u} />)}
</tbody>
```

Alternatively, and perhaps more conventionally, you can *destruct* the props in your `DataRow` component so that it only expects *one* prop, called `data`:

```
const DataRow: React.FC<Users> = ({data}) => {
```

Then you can just pass the entire object instead of its individual properties:

```
<tbody>
  {users.map(u => <DataRow data={u} />)}
</tbody>
```